# Referencing Lambda Source Files in Sibling Directory using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am attempting to deploy a Lambda function using Terraform, where my source files are in a different directory adjacent to where I have my Terraform files. I want to have Terraform do the zipping of the source files for me and deploy them into the Lambda. Terraform doesn't seem to want to recognize that my files are there, though.

My directory structure:

```
project_root/
  deployment/
    terraform/
      my-terraform.tf
  function_source/
    function.py
```

I want it to package everything in `function_source` directory (there is only one file there now, but may be more later) and drop it into the `deployment` directory.

My Terraform:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type          = "zip"
  output_path   = "../function.zip"
  source_dir    = "../../function_source/"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  filename          = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path}"
  function_name     = "my-function"
  role              = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn}"
  handler           = "function.handler"
  runtime           = "python3.7"
}
```

When I run this, though, I get the error message `data.archive_file.lambda_zip: data.archive_file.lambda_zip: error archiving directory: could not archive missing directory: ../../function_source/`

I have tried using absolute paths without success (which wouldn't be a good solution anyway). I have also tried creating the .zip file manually and hardcoding its directly in Lambda declaration, but it only works if I put the .zip file in my `terraform` directory. It seems Terraform can only see files in its own directory or below, but I'd rather not co-mingle my source files there. Is there a way to do this?

I am using Terraform v0.12.4

Comment: Interesting, your terraform code looks right and it should have worked. Terraform can see files above and I have tested on my machine. I guess the permissions of that directory has some issue? What's the output of "ls -sl project_root" bash command?

Comment: @congbaoguier I thought about file permissions too, but everything throughout my project has at least read permissions granted to User, Group, and Other. I have since rearranged my directories to put `function_source` underneath the `terraform` directory without any permission changes and now it can see and deploy the files fine. But I'd prefer not to have it arranged this way.